# How to implement SetFieldValue of my Custom Google Map Component with Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-google-maps

I'm new to react and formik. How would I implement setfieldvalue on my custom component (Location Picker)?

What I've tried so far is firing setfieldvalue on onDragEnd function

Here's the demo I've been working so far https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-napier-smjxj

When i drag the marker I get an error. My expected results would be to update the values of location object. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You do not directly have access to the marker position from the `onDragEnd` callback, you'd have to maintain refs in your parent component, also the `onChange` functions.(Also have to set ref callback for marker)

```
componentWillMount() {
    const { setFieldValue } = this.props;
    const refs = {};
    this.setState({
      position: null,
      setMarkerRef: ref => {
        refs.marker = ref;
      },
      onMarkerDrag: () => {
        const lat = refs.marker
          .getPosition()
          .lat()
          .toString();
        const lng = refs.marker
          .getPosition()
          .lng()
          .toString();
        setFieldValue('latLng',{lat, lng});
      }
);}
```

As above. Then you can pass it down to your MapComponent as a prop,

```
<MapComponent onDragEnd={this.state.onMarkerDrag}  onMarkerMounted={this.state.setMarkerRef} />
```

and then on your `<Marker/>`

```
    <Marker
       position={center}
       onDragEnd={onDragEnd}
       draggable={isMarkerDraggable}
       ref={props.onMarkerMounted}
     />
```